# Configuring Logging for Grails Standalone App Runner

Tags: tomcat, grails, configuration, grails-plugin, embedded-tomcat-7

I am writing a Grails app and would like to use the [Grails Standalone App Runner](http://grails.org/plugin/standalone) that packages your Grails app into a fat JAR with an embedded Tomcat container.

I would like to configure logging for the embedded Tomcat container will use to store and read SSL certs from. I want to specify log levels for different catalina components, and also replace log4j with logback using `SyslogAppender`.

**How/where do I make such configurations? Is this documented anywhere?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace log4j with logback, you can use [Logback Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/logback).

You need to add following lines in your BuildConfig.groovy.

```
dependencies {
   compile 'org.grails.plugins:logback:0.3.1'
}
```

You also need to exclude grails log4j plugin.

```
inherits('global') {
   excludes 'grails-plugin-log4j', 'log4j'
}
```

You also need to run

```
grails clean
```

to remove compiled files.

You can find more about the plugin [here](http://grails.org/plugin/logback).